# Why is “wave behavior” of EM field not observed at small frequencies?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electric-fields

In *Feynman’s lectures on Physics : Volume 1*, there is a table in *Chapter 2 : Basic Physics* that lists various frequencies in the electromagnetic field and relates them to the observed behavior (in the far right column):

[image: Electromagnetic spectrum]

This suggests that even at significant frequencies of oscillation of charges, i.e., at 100 Hz, “field behavior” of the EM field is seen and that “wave behavior” is seen only after the frequencies reach $10^5$ Hz.

Is it not true that even a small frequency of oscillation of charge should set up a wave in the EM field and that “field behavior” is seen only when charges are absolutely stationary? Also, what exactly is meant by “field behavior”?

Comment: At frequencies of the AC power grid (50/60 Hz), wavelengths are so large that it usually does not matter (diffraction, interference).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schumann_resonances   Here is a link on Schumann resonances  which go well below 60 Hz.  If the Earth were bigger the would be even lower frequency.  As Pieter points out below, if the wavelength is much bigger than your "lab" things are quasi-static.  There is no lower limit on wavelike behavior.

Comment: Look at the occupation number--the number of photons in a mode--I think it is really large at LF since $E=h\nu$--leading to classical (wave) behavior. Obviously, for a gamma ray, it is 1, a low quantum number--making QM important.

Comment: Note that the US navy uses extremely long wave radio to provided limited communications to submarines, thus taking advantage of the wave nature of light to lower frequency than shown in that chart. But look up what kind of hardware is involved and ask yourself what other situation justify the investment. Context, money and practicalities all matter when asking about technology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Waves behavior" are the phenomena of interference and diffraction. For humans, this is noticeable when the wavelength is on the human scale: meters, maybe kilometers.

For sound this means frequencies higher than a few cycles per second. When it is slower, we call these variations just changes in the atmospheric pressure. In oceans, the tides are too slow to be treated as water waves. In electromagnetism, human scale corresponds to frequencies of 100 MHz (FM broadcast).

Really slow variations (AC power, the teacher waving a charged rod), are much better dealt with using quasistatic models where wavelength can be disregarded.

Answer (score -1):

You should take the words "rough behavior" with a grain of salt, I mean is very rough. Fundamentally electromagnetism or radiation is a **field theory**. The full description is given by [QED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics) (quantum electrodynamics) so at any frequency, radiation IS described as a field, i.e. for the case of EM a 4-vector field $A_\mu$ which is defined at all times at every point in space, hence called a field. We identify its particle behavior as the excitation modes of this field. More specifically a field can be decomposed as a sum of modes (or waves if you wish) this modes are identified as particles depending on the context and energy scale, that was perhaps what Feynman was trying to convey with such table.

The short answer is then that the more localized the energy is, the closer you are to dealing with particle behavior, namely a defined trajectory and no interference/diffraction phenomena. An example of this is given by particle-like excitations such as [solitons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soliton). Or the spontaneous emission of light from an atom as an example of localization and particle behavior.

Comment: "Localized" does not have anything to do with this.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your critique please?

Comment: In what way would the energy be localized? Are you talking about coherence lengths? Those can be large or small at any frequency.

Comment: That is precisely what im trying to simplify for the OP.  I believe what confuses him is the dual behavior of light, so I am trying to explain under which conditions it is more useful to use a wave description instead of a classical/particle one

Comment: The poster was asking about the really low frequencies (the physics teacher waving with a charged rod etc). You answered with QFT, 4-vectors etc to "simplify" things? And then went on to confuse things even more with "definite trajectories".

Comment: My first paragraph wanted to give a fundamentalist answer mainly directed towards the last paragraph of the question. The second paragraph the simplified short general answer to what I believed was the possible confusion. Do you have any advise on how to improve my answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77195/discussion-between-ohneval-and-pieter).